# Jasper server rest service returns unauthorized

Tags: c#, jasper-reports, httpclient, jasperserver

Using .NET Http client i login to jasper server.

```
 HttpResponseMessage loginResponse = loginClient.PostAsync("http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/rest/login", formContent).Result;
IEnumerable<string> jaspsessid = loginResponse.Headers.GetValues("Set-Cookie");
```

Using above session id i pass to next request.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookie", jaspsessid);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 

System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
StringContent requestContent = constructJasperRequestJson(reportParameters);
HttpResponseMessage generateReportRequestResponse = new HttpResponseMessage();
generateReportRequestResponse = httpClient.PostAsync(AppConstant.JASPER_SERVER_BASE_URI + AppConstant.JASPER_SERVER_REPORT_EXECUTION_URI, requestContent).Result;
```

In second request i am getting 401.Unauthorized.

If anyone knows the issue,help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a CookieContainer to hold the session cookie, rather than setting a header.

See [How do I set a cookie on HttpClient's HttpRequestMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373738/how-do-i-set-a-cookie-on-httpclients-httprequestmessage) for an example.