# Session Cookies and HttpClient running in MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, azure-mobile-services

I'm struggling with an authentication issue between an MVC app and a Azure Mobile App.

The MVC app calls the Mobile App login end `https:<api>/.auth/login/microsoftaccout?post_url_login=location`

That all works, the Mobile app calls Live to authenticate and redirect all the way back to the MVC app works fine.

On the MVC site, any `<a>` links that point at the api authorise and return results as expected. But using an httpclient within a controller fails with a 401.

When I look at the trace and the Azure Mobile App log, clicking the `<a>` link I see an `AppServiceAuthSession` cookie added to the Request Header. The Httpclient trace does not have this.

How do I get the HttpClient to act the same way as if clicking an `<a>` link?

Comment: You can specify cookies/headers for the httpClient. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373738/

Answer (score 0):

You can add in a cookie such as:

```
var cookies = new CookieContainer();
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookies })
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://example.com")})
{
    var cookieDomain = "some domain";
    cookies.Add(cookieDomain, new Cookie("CookieName", "cookie_value"));

    // Use client
}
```

In theory you could read the cookie out of `Response.Cookies` on the MVC controller and pass the values through to your endpoint as needed.

Comment: Unfortunately niether of those two suggestions worked. When I add the cookie, the `Request.Header.Cookie` on the response says `AppServiceAuthSession=deleted`. When I look at the controller for `Reponse.Cookies`, there isn't one called `AppServiceAuthSession`.