# How to validate cookie in post request?

Tags: c#, rest, cookies, httpclient

I started with the following post to create my method:
[Stack Overflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373738/how-do-i-set-a-cookie-on-httpclients-httprequestmessage)

I created the following method:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage GetStuffFromRest(MyRequest myData)
    {
        var baseAddress = new Uri(_baseUri);
        var requestXML = CreateBody(myData);
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
        {
            #region Trying Cookie Container                
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", "myUserName");
            var c = new Cookie("Cookie", HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(myData.Cookie));
            cookieContainer.Add(baseAddress, c);

            response = httpClient.PostAsync(_myMethodUri, new StringContent(requestXML, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml")).Result;
            #endregion

        }

        return response;
    }
```

myData.Cookie is populated from another rest service that I called and obtained the cookie from.

When I call another web service I am getting a 401 status code back.

I believe it has to do with how I am passing the cookie to the rest service.

How can I verify what exactly my headers contain? (Particularly the cookie)

UPDATE:
Rephrased the question.

Comment: Can you show us the content of `myData.Cookie`

Comment: I added to the update.