# C# WebBrowser control - Get INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY => ASP.NET_SessionId

Tags: c#, cookies, webbrowser-control

I have a WebBrowser control in C# and now I need to get internet_cookie_httponly mean that ASP.NET_SessionId over webcontrol. But I'm using IE6 so that I can not use wininet.dll for this.
I have tried something same that:

```
var cookie = webBrowser1.Document.Cookie;
```

but it can not response ASP.NET_SessionId.
Please show me how can I get ASP.NET_SessionId over WebBrowser, thank you!

Comment: Why are you trying to get cookies from WebBrowser?  The cookies are stored in the user account settings and are common between all applications including IE and WebBrowser.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373738/how-do-i-set-a-cookie-on-httpclients-httprequestmessage

Comment: i'm building a web control for login a web page (asp), after that, I will get  ASP.NET_SessionId and use RestSharp for GET/POST. need ASP.NET_SessionId for authentication

Comment: The webbrowser would of stored the cookies in the user account settings so you can still get it from the user account and not from the webbrowser.

Comment: sorry nut i dont understand your mean?!