# Obtain AzureAppProxyAccessCookie when I have a valid Azure AD JWT token

Tags: azure-active-directory

Some background info:

I'm working on a two-factor authentication solution for some API by using

1. Azure AD
2. encoded api key

I'm able to get a valid access token pogrammatically to be used as authorization bearer token on the header request. Unfortunately, the API expects the 2) encoded api key to be delivered through the authorizaton field, and as such, I'm expected to use the pass AAD auth through a cookie instead.

If I direct chrome to my api and log in normally while capturing the traffic, I see that the cookie `AzureAppProxyAccessCookie` is set.

If i do a curl GET request with this cookie against my api, the response is successful.

TLDR/Actual question:
How can I obtain a valid `AzureAppProxyAccessCookie` programmatically when I already am able to obtain a valid JWT token?

Comment: Check this old SO thread which may be of some help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373738/how-do-i-set-a-cookie-on-httpclients-httprequestmessage

Comment: @hsp Did you ever discover how to retrieve the AzureAppProxyAccessCookie?