# How to read HttpResponseContent as Stream using system.net.http

Tags: c#, cookies, azure-functions

I have a piece of code to read `HttpResponseContent` using `windows.web.http`:

```
        using System.IO;
        using Windows.Web.Http;
        using Newtonsoft.Json;

        var responseContent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HttpResponseContent>(response.Content.ToString());
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Ok) 
        {
            //convert only from this line
            using (var input =
                await response.Content.ReadAsInputStreamAsync()
                                      .AsTask()
                                      .ConfigureAwait(false))
            using (var stream = input.AsStreamForRead())
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
            using (JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr)) //to this line
        {
                return DeserializeData(reader);
        }
```

**Question 1**: How can I achieve this using `system.net.http` namespace?

Note: I wrote those codes in `uwp` using `windows.web.http`, what I want is to convert that code using different package/namespace, which is `system.net.http` which I am using in Azure Functions.

**Reference Link:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http?view=netframework-4.7.2 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http

Thanks

Comment: what have you had problems with?

Comment: it is written for windows.web.http library, I want to convert it to system.net.http library, which is different, that code wont work on system.net.http, Iam using system.net.http because Iam making a project in azure function, which is not compatible with windows.web.http.

Comment: show us your attempt at doing this task, then if you run into a problem we can perhaps assist at that point.  or would you rather we just wrote the code for you?

Comment: sure I will edit the code base on I tried, regarding the reading as Stream, Iam not able to figure out the outcome of my change , cause of my issue from adding header, just a min
Thank You

Comment: Can you check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12374486/7075463

Comment: Hi I tried to just use  request.Headers.Add("SESSION", SessionId); on my current codebase(the one using windows.web.http) and works perfefctly.

btw here is how I call it:
var response = await _client.SendAsync(request, source.Token)
                        .ConfigureAwait(false);

Comment: It is a bit unclear: are you trying to add header to response that you are going to deliver to a client? Or to response that you have got from a server?

Comment: @Felix , CreateHttpRequestMessage is my base class , this will create the base address, and then as you can see , I added a header on my httprequestmessage using headers.add , then Iam calling the created httprequest message using .SendAsync.

Comment: I separated my questitons , here is the link from my other question from header:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53717977/how-to-properly-add-httprequestheaders-using-system-net-http-library

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using (var input =
                await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()
                                      .ConfigureAwait(false))
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(input))
            using (JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
            {
                return DeserializeData(reader);
            }
```