# How to properly add HttpRequestHeaders using system.net.http library

Tags: c#, azure-functions, system.net

I created a HttpRequestMessage with header using **windows.web.http;** library:

```
var request = base.CreateHttpRequestMessage();
        request.Headers.Add("SESSION", SessionId);
        return request;
```

and after sending SendRequestAsync(); , I am able to get the response successfully .

But in my case I need to use **system.net.http;** library, with same codes:

```
var request = base.CreateHttpRequestMessage();
        request.Headers.Add("SESSION", SessionId);
        return request;
```

but when I am calling the SendAsync(); , I am getting an UnAuthorized response.
Does anyone knows what causing the issue?

```
var source = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout)
var response = await _client.SendAsync(request, source.Token)
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

**NOTE:** I tried manually setting same valid **SessionId** for both , on **windows.web.http** its Okay, but on **system.net.http** its unauthorized.

How I initialize my HttpClient:

```
private HttpClientHandler handler;
handler = new HttpClientHandler();

private HttpClient _client;
_client = new HttpClient(handler)
```

**Reference Link:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http?view=netframework-4.7.2 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http

**Requests Header format:**
windows.web.http:
[image]
system.net.http:
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: About `use system.net.http`, do you mean to use `system.net.http.HttpClient`?

Comment: @JerryLiu yes...

Comment: So you have written code using HttpClient but got UnAuthorized? Could you post your code using HttpClient, on my side I could get Session header successfully.

Comment: when calling HttpClient.SendAsync(); , our api service returns unauthorized, even I added the valid session on the header

Comment: updated the question , attached the screenshot of the request

Comment: Is it possible the problem is related to how the api service handles the request?

Comment: @JerryLiu , yes its possible, but what I am confused is why on windows.web.http library, its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging the request using Fiddler, I found out that the cookie of my request is null, so I fixed this by adding the cookie instead of adding the header.

```
CookieContainer.Add(request.RequestUri, new Cookie("SESSION", SessionId));
```

Answer (score 0):

One disadvantage of **system.net.http** is that
doesn't cache requests. Server that doesn't send
`Cache-Control` can be potential problem.

Comment: Hi Thank You, could you please elaborate more please?

Comment: updated the question , attached the screenshot of the request