# HttpRequestMessage doesn't add Cookie into request

Tags: c#, network-programming, httpclient, dotnet-httpclient

I make a simple POST request via HttpClient from my Console applications

```
HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage { Method = method };
requestMessage.Headers.Add("custom1", "c1");
requestMessage.Headers.Add("custom2", "c2");
requestMessage.Headers.Add("Cookie", "c3");
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
using (var response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage, cancellationToken))
using (var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
{
    //...
}
```

When I see Request Headers in [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler), I only see the first two headers - custom1 and custom2, and no "Cookie" header.

I use VS2017 and .NET 4.7

Comment: please try ˋset-cookieˋ as explained here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie

Comment: @arnonuem set-cookie is for response, but I make a request

Comment: Usually the server sets the cookies  which the browser eventually stores.

Comment: @arnonuem I added to my question that I use console application.

Comment: Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373738/how-do-i-set-a-cookie-on-httpclients-httprequestmessage

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set a cookie on HttpClient's HttpRequestMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373738/how-do-i-set-a-cookie-on-httpclients-httprequestmessage)

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya your comment helped me. The problem was UseCookies=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't add cookies with simply adding a header because there are things that `CookieContainer` and `HttpCookie` will handle for you, things such as Expiration, Path, Domain and correct way of setting name and values for cookies.

The better way is to use [CookieContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.cookiecontainer?view=netframework-4.8).

```
var baseAddress = new Uri('http://localhost');

HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage { Method = method };
requestMessage.Headers.Add("custom1", "c1");
requestMessage.Headers.Add("custom2", "c2");
// requestMessage.Headers.Add("Cookie", "c3"); wrong way to do it

var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
{
   using(HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
   {
       cookieContainer.Add(baseAddress, new Cookie("CookieName", "cookie_value"));
       using (var response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage, cancellationToken))
       using (var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
       {
              // do your stuff
       }
   }
}
```

**Off-topic recommendation**:

DO NOT create a new instance of HttpClient every time. It will cause all sockets get busy. Please follow better approaches like singleton or [HttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests).

Comment: Why the use of CookieContainer is the correct way compared to adding headers?
And thank you regarding HttpClientFactory although it is related to .NET Core

Comment: @amplifier Because with CookieContainer you can easily take care of expiration, path, domain  **and not be worried about `do I need to escape or encode the name or value for cookies?`**.  Take a look at [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) header on MDN. 

And yes HttpClientFactory is a .NET Core thing but don't forget that YOU SHOULD MAKE YOUR `HttpClient` instance singletone.