# ServiceStack Http Utils Set Cookie

Tags: http, cookies, servicestack, webrequest

I am trying to use ServiceStacks Http Utils, but for some reason I can't seem to be able to set the JSession cookie I received from logging in via basic auth.  This is what I've tried so far...

response = imiLogin.PostToUrl("", requestFilter: req =>
            {req.Headers["Cookie"] = sessionCookie.message;}).FromJson();

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ServiceStack's [HTTP Utils](https://docs.servicestack.net/http-utils) is a wrapper around .NET's [HttpWebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=netframework-4.8) where you would use the [HttpWebRequest.CookieContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer?view=netframework-4.8) to set cookies, e.g:

```
url.PostJsonToUrl(body, requestFilter: req =>
        req.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie("name", "value", "/")))
    .FromJson<Response>();
```

Comment: What is the recommended way to add a cookie via HttpUtils now that the request filter is using HttpRequestMessage rather than HttpWebRequest?

Comment: Can't be done on the request, you'll need to [configure the HttpClient](https://docs.servicestack.net/http-utils#connect-to-httpfactory) to [include cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12373738/85785).