# How to add a cookie to a request using HttpClient from IHttpClientFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, httpclientfactory

**Background**
I'm working on an ASP.NET Core Web API where we within our API call a 3rd party API. This 3rd party API requires every request to contain a cookie with an access token. Our API gets this token from a claim (from the `ClaimsPrincipal` of the user associated with the request).

**Details**
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12374486/310001) shows how to set a cookie on a request, but the example requires that one manually constructs the `HttpClient` (to be able to inject a `HttpClientHandler` with a `CookieContainer`). And since it is not desirable to do manual instantiation of the `HttpClient`, I would rather get the `HttpClient` injected through DI, which [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) illustrates (usin `IHttpClientFactory`).

In my service, I have access to a an injected `HttpClient` instance (`_httpClient`), and the most simple function looks like this:

```
public async Task<string> GetStatusAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user)
{
    // TODO: Add cookie with access token (from user's claims) before making request
    return await _httpClient.GetStringAsync(Endpoints.Status);
}
```

[This GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20062) asks about how to include authorization cookie when using IHttpClientFactory, and the answer says to [use the header propagation middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#header-propagation-middleware). And now to my issue:

From what I can see, you set up the header propagation middleware (with all headers and cookies and whatnot) during service configuration at application startup. In our API however, I do not have the value for the authentication cookie before actually making the request to the 3rd party API.

**Question**
How can I add a cookie to the request on a `HttpClient` instance that is injected to my service using `IHttpClientFactory`, right before making the actual request?

Comment: You can use the `ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler()` method to configure the main handler when you setup HttpClientFactory, which should allow you to configure cookies using the `Cookie` class using an `HttpClientHandler`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientbuilderextensions.configureprimaryhttpmessagehandler?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution was indeed to use [header propagation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#header-propagation-middleware). I just had to get all the pieces together correctly.

Header propagation is configured inside `ConfigureServices` (in `Startup.cs`). And since I want to use data from the current user's claims, the trick is, when adding the cookie header, to use on of the overloads that takes in a function that gives you access to the current context:

```
services.AddHeaderPropagation(options =>
{
    options.Headers.Add("Cookie", context =>
    {
        var accessToken = context.HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "access-token")?.Value;
        return accessToken != null ? new StringValues($"token={accessToken}") : new StringValues();
    });
});
```

In addition to this, since I'm using a [Typed Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests#how-to-use-typed-clients-with-ihttpclientfactory), I also had to configure that that specific service should forward the cookie header (at the same place inside `ConfigureServices` in `Startup.cs`):

```
services.AddHttpClient<IApiService, ApiService>(httpClient =>
{
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://httpbin.org/");
}).AddHeaderPropagation(options =>
{
    options.Headers.Add("Cookie");
});
```

And finally, the thing that caused me some trouble for a little while: Since I'm using data from the current users claims, the registration of the header propagation middleware (`app.UseHeaderPropagation();` inside `Configure` in `Startup.cs`) must happen *after* adding the authentication middleware (`app.UseAuthentication();`). If not, the claims haven't been set yet.

And as a final tip: I head great us in https://httpbin.org/ when working on this. The request inspection endpoints there are really useful to see what data you actually pass along in your request.

Answer (score 3):

You can put a static function inside AddHeaderPropagation config function:

```
services.AddHeaderPropagation(options =>
    {
        options.Headers.Add(MyCookie());
    });
```

And inside `MyCookie` function,
get the current context end extract from them all needed data.

If you need something from your current flow or current controller you can add it
inside httpSession and take it inside `MyCookie` function.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The solution was to use header propagation, but using the current context (available through one of the `Headers.Add` overloads) as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62696725/310001

Comment: I seem to hit: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70301368/useheaderpropagation-not-recognized-during-debug-run