# UseHeaderPropagation not recognized during debug run

Tags: c#, .net-core, request-headers, hotchocolate

I'm working on adding propagation to HotChocolate GraphQL server but simply can't get it working.

I've configured my propagation in my `ConfigureServices services.AddHeaderPropagation(o => o.Headers.Add("Authorization"));`

I've added it to my `httpClient: services.AddHttpClient(AssumptionManagement, c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:19801")).AddHeaderPropagation();`

I've added it in my Configure method:
`app.UseHeaderPropagation();`

Despite all this it still gives me the following error when I run the app in debug:

```
An unhandled exception of type System.InvalidOperationException occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: The HeaderPropagationValues.Headers property has not been initialized.
```

Register the header propagation middleware by adding `app.UseHeaderPropagation()` in the `Configure(...)` method. Header propagation can only be used within the context of an HTTP request.'

Am I just not seeing something here or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.HeaderPropagation` nuget package installed?

Comment: Also, check where `app.UseHeaderPropagation();` is called. I put it after `app.UseStaticFiles();` and before `app.UseRouting();` as shown here: https://thecodeblogger.com/2021/05/25/request-header-propagation-in-net-core-web-applications/.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this - I have the same problem

Comment: Are you using `InitializeOnStartup`? I ran into this same scenario and after disabling `InitializeOnStartup` this issue went away. I'm still looking into _why_. My guess is that the warm up is using the services config, but not the middleware.

Comment: was it because of the source of the request being from a middleware instead of controller?

Comment: @Nathan That is the issue I am facing. header propagation works fine everywhere unless the httpClient in question is called from my auth middleware - do you have any suggestsions ?

Answer (score 1):

As I understood from you're trying to make call from auth middleware? In such case make sure that `app.UseHeaderPropagation()` is called prior to the middleware that is relying on header propagation.

Comment: In my case, it worked after calling app.UseHeaderPropagation first.