# Do pooled HttpClient instances keep the CookieContainer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, httpclientfactory

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12374486/16241) shows how to add a cookie to an HttpClient request.  But one of the comments warns that `CookieContainer` is cached on the HttpClient.  Most of my cookies should not be sent again for a different user.

I am hoping that the `HttpClientFactory` cleans things like added `CookieContainer`s off the instance of the HttpClient that is in its pool.

**If I get my `HttpClient` by calling `httpClientFactory.CreateClient` is there a chance that the one I get will have a previous `CookieContainer` on it?**

Update:

The answer to my question is yes!  `CookieContainer` is intended for when you want to send the same cookie with every call.

If you need to send a different cookie with each call, there are several ways to do that.  But the easiest is to put it in the header.

Because the `HttpClientFactory` creates a new `HttpClient` with each request for a client, you can add to the headers of the client and not worry about it reusing the cookie.

The key to doing this is the setting `UseCookies`.  It HAS to be set to false or the cookies you add to the headers will be ignored.  Once you do that, you can add the cookies to your header under the key "Cookies" and enter them as semicolon separated key value pairs (with an equal sign between them).  Your cookies come back in the header "Set-Cookies".

Comment: I'm not sure if this information is still accurate or whether the behavior might have been changed by now but this issue link is from the ASP.NET Core Docs GitHub regarding this. Seems odd to me, considering it's recommended to use the factory and reuse client instances https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/pull/15855/files

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's the `HttpMessageHandler` instances that get pooled; not the `HttpClient` instances. By default, the *handlers* have a lifetime of 2 minutes, which means it's *very* possible that a `CookieContainer` will be shared between multiple `HttpClient`s.

There's a [section in the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests#cookies), which explains that automatic cookie handling and `IHttpClientFactory` don't work well together:

> The pooled `HttpMessageHandler` instances results in `CookieContainer` objects being shared. Unanticipated `CookieContainer` object sharing often results in incorrect code. For apps that require cookies, consider either:
>
> - Disabling automatic cookie handling
> - Avoiding `IHttpClientFactory`
>
> Call [ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientbuilderextensions.configureprimaryhttpmessagehandler) to disable automatic cookie handling:
>
> ```
> services.AddHttpClient("configured-disable-automatic-cookies")
>     .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
>     {
>         return new SocketsHttpHandler()
>         {
>             UseCookies = false,
>         };
>     });
> ```

Comment: What does setting `UseCookies = false` do?  Does it mean that `CookieContainer`s are not cached, or that they just do not work?  (I have seen examples that add the cookie directly as a header, is that the recommend way with `UseCookies` set to `false`?

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13287224) covers both of your points. It means you can set the cookies using traditional HTTP headers. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64157842/2630078) shows a different approach, if you just want to forward cookies from an incoming request.

Answer (score 5):

The fact that `CookieContainer` is tightly coupled to `HttpClient` is a major design flaw in my opinion, because it doesn't allow you to (correctly) use a single instance of the latter while simulating multiple cookie "sessions". As pointed out, `HttpClientFactory` doesn't solve this - you're still stuck with either abandoning `CookieContainer` and processing the raw headers yourself, or having more `HttpClient` instances than you really need.

I recently [solved this problem with Flurl](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/506) as a major new feature in 3.0. If you don't mind the library dependency, it's all `HttpClient` under the hood, but it replaces `CookieContainer` with a similar concept (`CookieJar`) that supports the same automatic cookie handling but makes single-client/multi-session scenarios possible.

Answer (score 3):

It's kinda tricky to find the implementation of the `HttpClientFactory`.

It has been moved from one repo to another over the years:

1. [aspnet/HttpClientFactory](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpClientFactory)
2. [dotnet/Extensions](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions)
3. [dotnet/Runtime](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime)

We are interested about the [DefaultHttpClientFactory](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DefaultHttpClientFactory.cs).

Let's look at the [CreateClient](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DefaultHttpClientFactory.cs#L117) first :

```cs
public HttpClient CreateClient(string name)
{
    if (name == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
    }

    HttpMessageHandler handler = CreateHandler(name);
    var client = new HttpClient(handler, disposeHandler: false);

    HttpClientFactoryOptions options = _optionsMonitor.Get(name);
    for (int i = 0; i < options.HttpClientActions.Count; i++)
    {
        options.HttpClientActions[i](client);
    }

    return client;
}
```

As you can see it calls the [CreateHandler](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DefaultHttpClientFactory.cs#L136) method to retrieve a `HttpMessageHandler`:

```cs
public HttpMessageHandler CreateHandler(string name)
{
    if (name == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
    }

    ActiveHandlerTrackingEntry entry = _activeHandlers.GetOrAdd(name, _entryFactory).Value;

    StartHandlerEntryTimer(entry);

    return entry.Handler;
}
```

The `_activeHandlers` definition [looks like this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DefaultHttpClientFactory.cs#L101):

```cs
_activeHandlers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<ActiveHandlerTrackingEntry>>(StringComparer.Ordinal);
_entryFactory = (name) =>
{
    return new Lazy<ActiveHandlerTrackingEntry>(() =>
    {
        return CreateHandlerEntry(name);
    }, LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);
};
```

If you want to you can jump to the internal [CreateHandlerEntry](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DefaultHttpClientFactory.cs#L151) method which initalizes a new handler, but I think it is out of scope from the topic perspective.

So as you can see there is no logic which would do any sort of cleanup when you get an already existing instance. Via `optionsMonitor`'s `HttpClientActions` or `HttpMessageHandlerBuilderActions` can you inject some code, like [they did during testing](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/tests/Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Tests/DefaultHttpClientFactoryTest.cs).

[Stephen Gordon has written an article](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclient-creation-and-disposal-internals-should-i-dispose-of-httpclient) about creation and disposal of HttpClient instances it worths reading it.