Add cookies to the API request in Blazor
I'm using the blazor web application with auto interaction and individual accounts, I'm trying to make a request to the API but the cookies aren't passed on in the request, how do I add them?
return await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<UserDTO>>("api/users");


I need suggestions, I've been trying to solve this problem for some time, but without success.

"but the cookies aren't passed on in the request," - where is your code where you add them?

nowhere because what I tried didn't work, I don't know how to add them...

You'll need to do using( HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage( HttpMethod.Get, "/api/users" ) { Headers = { Cookies = { yourCookies } } and then pass req into await _httpClient.SendAsync(.

what you sent cannot be added to my service. where do I put that code?

Please see all the examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373738/how-do-i-set-a-cookie-on-httpclients-httprequestmessage

For blazor with individual asp.net identity, if you request for webapi in the server project, you could use token.

but I'm making the request in my client to the api and I don't want tokens, I want to pass my cookie identity inside my request so that the api knows if it's authorised or not.

There is no built-in way for the demand. You will need to get the authentication cookie on your own. After login, then asp.net core identity cookie will be generated to the domain with the cookie name .AspNetCore.Identity.Application

Then you need to get the cookie before httpclient request. WASM will experience 2 rendermodes: prerender and interactive. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-8.0#ihttpcontextaccessorhttpcontext-in-razor-components-blazor) 
When prerender : HttpContext is available. Js Interop not available. You could get cookie by httpContext.request.cookie. 
When interactive : HttpContext is not available. Js Interop is available. You could get cookie by javascript "document.cookie".
So you could do following :
Install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http 2.2.2 at client project, then call backend in an WASM page like
@page "/counter"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly

@inject IJSRuntime _js

@data

<script>
    function ReadCookie(name) {
        const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;   
        const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
        if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(';').shift();
    }
</script>


@code {
    string data = "";
    [CascadingParameter]
    HttpContext? httpContext{ get; set; }


    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        string authcookie;
        if (httpContext != null)
        {
            //when prerender get cookie from httpContext
            authcookie = httpContext.Request.Cookies[".AspNetCore.Identity.Application"];
        }
        else
        {
            //when interactive get cookie by js interop
            authcookie = await _js.InvokeAsync<string>("ReadCookie", ".AspNetCore.Identity.Application");
        }


        if (authcookie != null)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://localhost:7264/test"); //the [Authorize] webapi endpoint
            // Add a cookie to the request headers
            request.Headers.Add("Cookie", $".AspNetCore.Identity.Application={authcookie}");

            // Send the request
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            data = "no authentication cookie";
        }
    }
}

Need to set cookie httponly to false in server project program.cs.
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
});


when prerender, it works, but if it's interactive, it doesn't, maybe the script has some problem, i dont know. Does it work for you when interactive?

@FranciscoFernandes you could try set cookie.httponly to false to enable javascript access cookie  as i updated answer at bottom.

didn't work, document.cookie is still empty

@FranciscoFernandes make sure you added it to server project and use browser f12 to test if you could get document.cookie from console cli.

document.cookie remains empty in server components.

@FranciscoFernandes That's strange. At least you should have use f12 to get document.cookie.

I click f12, write console.log(document.cookie) and the console return a row empty and another row saying undefined.

@FranciscoFernandes Did you change the cookie name in server project? Use something like AddCookie(...)

I haven't changed the name of the cookie. The cookie I want is .AspNetCore.Identity.Application, created automatically at login, so is it supposed to appear in document.cookie without AddCookie or not?

@FranciscoFernandes Sure,it should appear. I have tested this solution all works well.  document.cookie is basic js command which needn't other configuration.

I have created a new project to test with .net8, individual accounts, interactive per page. I run the application, f12, I have the antiforgery cookie in the browser, so I think it should be returned in the console, but I write console.log(document.cookie), and I get the same result (empty with undefined). I don't know how it's working for you... But thanks for trying to help me.

@FranciscoFernandes I reproduced cannot get get document.cookie when i didn't set httponly to false in "Server" project (start from a new auto template). Hope this helps you.
