# Getting json string programmatically C#

Tags: c#, json, webclient

I am trying to get json string from a url by using following line of code. When I enter the url in Google Chrome I get whole string and data. but when I use my code it returns only this line of string 
*{"expand":"projects","projects":[]}*
 it is exact what I get when I enter the url in IE 10. How can I get same data that I get when I enter the url in Chrome? here is my code to get the json data.
 `var jsonStr = new WebClient().DownloadString("https_my_url");`

Comment: get the [json.net](http://json.codeplex.com/) library to serialize / deserialize any json you encounter.

Comment: Does the web site/service you are communicating with require any kind of authentication? Without knowing what site/service you are talking to, its quite difficult to help.

Comment: @Adrian, I don't see what authentication has to do with the OP's question?

Comment: Because the data returned from Chrome is different when returned by WebClient. My theory is that, if the request was authenticated then the data returned would be different.

Comment: @user217648 What string do you get back in each case?

Comment: Adrian, when I enter the url in chrome I get back a very long string which contins data I want to. but my code and IE10 returns only one line of string which is {"expand":"projects","projects":[]}

Comment: It really sounds like Chrome is returning different data. Have you logged on to the site in Chrome? Chrome may be passing an authentication token in a cookie. WebClient and IE may not have this token because you have not logged in.

Comment: Adrian, I tested your code it returned same result, only difference was it formated it in three lines instead. same result but it added line break.

Comment: Adrian, you are right, I tried to log on to the site in IE. now it returns same as chrome but it prompts to open/save a file instead.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to authenticate the request via WebClient.

See this answer for how to do that if the site uses Forms Authentication.

[WebClient accessing page with credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118712/webclient-accessing-page-with-credentials)

Comment: Thank you Adrian, It seems you need to send your username and password to the server, which I am not allowed to do. Is it possible to use coockie by getting jira's logon page once and having some kind of token or something to use? or using oauth? I am trying to find a solution.

Comment: I don't know much about JIRA but some searching lead me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869780/jira-rest-api-login-using-c-sharp Also Atalssian/JIRA documentation seems very thorough https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Example+-+Basic+Authentication

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a JSON parser to turn it in to something useful.  [`ServiceStack.Text`](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) (available via NuGet or download) has an excellent one that can turn json strings in to first-class POCOs.

```
using ServiceStack.Text;

public sealed class SomeObject
{
    public string expand { get; set; }
    public List<string> projects {get; set; }
}
```

And convert thusly:

```
SomeObject object = jsonString.FromJson<SomeObject>();
```

Note, I would make my POCOs a little more c# friendly and alias away the lower-case:

```
using ServiceStack.Text;
using ServiceStack.DataAnnotations;

public sealed class SomeObject
{
    [Alias("expand")]
    public string Expand { get; set; }

    [Alias("projects")]
    public List<string> Projects {get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is this relevant to the OP? The question's about receiving different strings between WebClient,Chrome and IE. not JSON de/serialization.

Comment: It *is* about JSON de/serialization (as far as I can tell!) The reason he sees fully formed results in Chrome is because Chrome *knows* it is JSON and is formatting the result appropriately.  In his code, he just gets a string back.  See the end of his question where he is assigning the result to a basic string.

Comment: It is my first time working with json, does it means that WebClient.DownloadString("") returns whole json data? does it menas that it gets json data but it cannot deserialze it? thanks

Comment: @user217648, correct - `WebClient.DownloadString` will just return the raw, unformatted, string.  To easily work with the data you need to de-serialize it.  The ServiceStack.Text library has one of the most (if not *the* most) high-performance JSON serializing/deserializing.