# How to do encryption using AES algorithm

Tags: java, c#, encryption

I have given a .key (abc.key) file.
Using the above .key file, encryption and decryption is done in Java. Here i need to implement same encryption and decryption functionality using C#.net.

Please give me idea on how to crack this. I am a newbie to these cryptography stuff.

Some of parameters they are setting in java are below. hope it will give little idea

```
    String keyFile="abc.key";
    String keyAlgorithm= "AES";
    String cipherTransformation="AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
    String needtoEncStr = "Password1";
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

UPDATED :

@daveBM: I used bouncycastle but m getting different result(not same as java output). below is my complete code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Engines;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Generators;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Modes;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Paddings;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities.Encoders;

public class BCEngine
{
    private readonly Encoding _encoding;
    private readonly IBlockCipher _blockCipher;
    private PaddedBufferedBlockCipher _cipher;
    private IBlockCipherPadding _padding;

    public BCEngine(IBlockCipher blockCipher, Encoding encoding)
    {
        _blockCipher = blockCipher;
        _encoding = encoding;
    }

    public void SetPadding(IBlockCipherPadding padding)
    {
        if (padding != null)
            _padding = padding;
    }

    public string Encrypt(string plain, string key)
    {
        byte[] result = BouncyCastleCrypto(true, _encoding.GetBytes(plain), key);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(result);
    }

    public string Decrypt(string cipher, string key)
    {
        byte[] result = BouncyCastleCrypto(false, Convert.FromBase64String(cipher), key);
        return _encoding.GetString(result);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="forEncrypt"></param>
    /// <param name="input"></param>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <exception cref="CryptoException"></exception>
    private byte[] BouncyCastleCrypto(bool forEncrypt, byte[] input, string key)
    {
        try
        {
            _cipher = _padding == null ? new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(_blockCipher) : new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(_blockCipher, _padding);
            byte[] keyByte = _encoding.GetBytes(key);
            _cipher.Init(forEncrypt, new KeyParameter(keyByte));
            return _cipher.DoFinal(input);
        }
        catch (Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.CryptoException ex)
        {
            throw new CryptoException(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}



static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Encoding _encoding;
            IBlockCipherPadding _padding;
            string key = "abc.key";

            Stream inStr = null;
            inStr = File.OpenRead(key);

            Stream stream = inStr;

            byte[] bytes = new byte[stream.Length];

            stream.Position = 0;

            stream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);

            string data1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes); // this is your string.


            _encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
            Pkcs7Padding pkcs = new Pkcs7Padding();
            _padding = pkcs;  

            BCEngine bcEngine = new BCEngine(new AesEngine(), _encoding);
            bcEngine.SetPadding(_padding);
            string data=bcEngine.Encrypt("AbcDefg12$", data1);

        }
```

I am getting this output "S2jjvVJVKfGodPfMuI4v+g==" when my expected output is "3df36eb77ccfc05e264a6212c2db5380"... Please let me know what is going wrong.

Comment: Probably not a very good idea to publish your secret key worldwide.

Comment: Answered here:http://lamahashim.blogspot.com/2009/08/encyptiondecryption-in-c-and-java.html

Comment: use the bouncy castle library - and do some googling - its a lot easier to work with www.bouncycastle.org

Comment: Another possibility here: http://zenu.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/aes-128bit-cross-platform-java-and-c-encryption-compatibility/

Comment: @daveBM: I used bouncycastle but m getting different result(not same as java output). See my complete updated code

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code that someone kindly posted in some other related question.

[Encrypting & Decrypting a String in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168240/encrypting-decrypting-a-string-in-c-sharp)

What you need to do is use the method **Encrypt(string plainText, string passPhrase)** where the **plainText** is whatever you want to encrypt and the **passPhrase** is the content of your .key file.

By the way, just mentioning that you had a .key file was enough. We don't need to know the content :)..

Hope that helps