# Encryption and decryption error

Tags: c#, encryption

I have a rather simple code for encryption and decryption. However, when I encrypt then decrypt, the output is not what I originally input.

This is the encryption:

```
static byte[] Encrypt(SymmetricAlgorithm aesAlg, string plainText)
    {
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

        using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                {
                    swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                }
                return msEncrypt.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

Decryption:

```
static string Decrypt(SymmetricAlgorithm aesAlg, byte[] cipherText)
    {
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

        using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
        {
            using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                {
                    return srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Main:

```
public static void Main()
    {
        string original = "My secret data!";

        using (SymmetricAlgorithm symmetricAlgorithm = new AesManaged())
        {
            byte[] encrypted = Encrypt(symmetricAlgorithm, original);
            string roundtrip = Decrypt(symmetricAlgorithm, encrypted);

            Console.WriteLine("Original: {0}", original);
            Console.WriteLine("RoundTrip: {0}", roundtrip);
        }
    }
```

Ouput should be:

```
Original: My secret data!
RoundTrip: My secret data!
```

However, it comes out as:

```
Original: My secret data!
RoundTrip: ">�����6dB&JD䮦�L�ܹ�SKo\v*.�"
```

or something funny like that.

I couldn't find anything helpful on the internet. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: use aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV); for decryption

Comment: So this is a typo question and should be closed as such.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encrypting & Decrypting a String in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168240/encrypting-decrypting-a-string-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your `Decrypt` method you create another encryptor, not a `Decryptor`!

If you change the line

```
aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
```

to

```
aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
```

Then you will get the decypted text.

Answer (score -1):

Decryption code

```
static string Decrypt(SymmetricAlgorithm aesAlg, byte[] cipherText)
{
    ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

    using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
    {
        using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        {
            using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
            {
                return srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what is it you're saying besides a code dump?