# Decrypt an encrypted text

Tags: c#, encryption

I got a textbox and a 'decrypt' button in my Windows Form Application where I put an encrypted string in there and try to decrypt it but the problem is this. First, I got this class code called `DataEncryptor` from a guy on this website:

```
public class DataEncryptor
{
    TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider symm;

    #region Factory
    public DataEncryptor()
    {
        this.symm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        this.symm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    }
    public DataEncryptor(TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider keys)
    {
        this.symm = keys;
    }

    public DataEncryptor(byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        this.symm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        this.symm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        this.symm.Key = key;
        this.symm.IV = iv;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider Algorithm
    {
        get { return symm; }
        set { symm = value; }
    }
    public byte[] Key
    {
        get { return symm.Key; }
        set { symm.Key = value; }
    }
    public byte[] IV
    {
        get { return symm.IV; }
        set { symm.IV = value; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Crypto

    public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data) { return Encrypt(data, data.Length); }
    public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data, int length)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create a MemoryStream.
            var ms = new MemoryStream();

            // Create a CryptoStream using the MemoryStream 
            // and the passed key and initialization vector (IV).
            var cs = new CryptoStream(ms,
                symm.CreateEncryptor(symm.Key, symm.IV),
                CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            // Write the byte array to the crypto stream and flush it.
            cs.Write(data, 0, length);
            cs.FlushFinalBlock();

            // Get an array of bytes from the 
            // MemoryStream that holds the 
            // encrypted data.
            byte[] ret = ms.ToArray();

            // Close the streams.
            cs.Close();
            ms.Close();

            // Return the encrypted buffer.
            return ret;
        }
        catch (CryptographicException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A cryptographic error occured: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public string EncryptString(string text)
    {
        return Convert.ToBase64String(Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text)));
    }

    public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] data) { return Decrypt(data, data.Length); }
    public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] data, int length)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create a new MemoryStream using the passed 
            // array of encrypted data.
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);

            // Create a CryptoStream using the MemoryStream 
            // and the passed key and initialization vector (IV).
            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms,
                symm.CreateDecryptor(symm.Key, symm.IV),
                CryptoStreamMode.Read);

            // Create buffer to hold the decrypted data.
            byte[] result = new byte[length];

            // Read the decrypted data out of the crypto stream
            // and place it into the temporary buffer.
            cs.Read(result, 0, result.Length);
            return result;
        }
        catch (CryptographicException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A cryptographic error occured: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public string DecryptString(string data)
    {
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(data))).TrimEnd('\0');
    }

    #endregion

}
```

And he gave the usage of it:

```
string message="A very secret message here.";
DataEncryptor keys=new DataEncryptor();
string encr=keys.EncryptString(message);

// later
string actual=keys.DecryptString(encr);
```

I copied his code and works at encrypting and decrypting:

```
//my code
private void proceedED(string data)
{
    DataEncryptor key = new DataEncryptor();
    string encr = key.EncryptString(data);
    string actual = key.DecryptString(encr);
    encryptedLabel.Text = encr;
    decryptedLabel.Text = actual;     
}
```

Then I created a method like this:

```
private void proceedDecrypt(string data) 
{
    DataEncryptor key = new DataEncryptor();
    string decr = key.DecryptString(data);
    decryptedData.Text = decr;
}
```

The problem is that it crashes when I submit and I don't know why.
I think it should be a true encrypted string because it's just a normal string.
How do I fix this?

Comment: What exception is it giving? In all posts about "errors", "crahes" etc. include the message and stacktrace of an exception? Maybe, you haven't initialized a key or something's wrong with your `data`. We can't know it without an exception message.

Comment: `Array cannot be null 
Paramater name: bytes` the line error is in the DecryptString(string data) method at the bottom of the DataEncryptor class

Comment: It looks like you created method `proceedDecrypt` but pass empty `data` to it. Looks at the place you call this method.

Comment: i think it needs to be a true encrypted string because its just a normal string

Comment: Hmm, this code looks quite familiar to me. See  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10176980/380384

Comment: Related post: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12071/how-to-store-iv-and-key-temporarily-but-securely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally solved it...

I copied this code from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d6a2836a-d587-4068-8630-94f4fb2a2aeb/encrypt-and-decrypt-a-string-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral

```
    static readonly string PasswordHash = "P@@Sw0rd";
    static readonly string SaltKey = "S@LT&KEY";
    static readonly string VIKey = "@1B2c3D4e5F6g7H8";

    public static string Encrypt(string plainText)
    {
        byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);

        byte[] keyBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(PasswordHash, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SaltKey)).GetBytes(256 / 8);
        var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged() { Mode = CipherMode.CBC, Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros };
        var encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(VIKey));

        byte[] cipherTextBytes;

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                cryptoStream.Close();
            }
            memoryStream.Close();
        }
        return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
    }
    public static string Decrypt(string encryptedText)
    {
        byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);
        byte[] keyBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(PasswordHash, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SaltKey)).GetBytes(256 / 8);
        var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged() { Mode = CipherMode.CBC, Padding = PaddingMode.None };

        var decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(VIKey));
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes);
        var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];

        int decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
        memoryStream.Close();
        cryptoStream.Close();
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount).TrimEnd("\0".ToCharArray());
    }
```

and removed the `DataEncryptor` class

Answer (score 1):

Each instance of `DataEncryptor` generates new keys. You need to use the same keys which encrypted the string to decrypt. If this is done in the same process then keep a reference to `DataEncryptor key`. Otherwise you need to initialize using the `DataEncryptor(byte[] key, byte[] iv)` constructor.

Try code like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string key, iv;

        var plain="A very secret message.";
        var cipher=EncryptString(plain, out key, out iv);

        // Later ...

        var message=DecryptString(cipher, key, iv);
    }

    public static string EncryptString(string plain, out string key, out string iv)
    {
        var crypto=new DataEncryptor();
        iv=Convert.ToBase64String(crypto.IV);
        key=Convert.ToBase64String(crypto.Key);
        return crypto.EncryptString(plain);
    }

    public static string DecryptString(string cipher, string key, string iv)
    {
        var crypto=new DataEncryptor(
            Convert.FromBase64String(key), 
            Convert.FromBase64String(iv));

        return crypto.DecryptString(cipher);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are creating new object in both function;

```
DataEncryptor key = new DataEncryptor();
```

That is the reason, for your error.

Just declare;

```
   DataEncryptor key = new DataEncryptor();
```

Out side of your proceedED() and proceedDecrypt(), I mean make it public.

OR you can pass pass key as parameter to proceedDecrypt() and use it in that function.

Like;

```
DataEncryptor key = new DataEncryptor();

private void proceedED(string data)
{
  string encr = key.EncryptString(data);
  string actual = key.DecryptString(encr);
  encryptedLabel.Text = encr;
  decryptedLabel.Text = actual; 
  proceedDecrypt(encr);    
}

private void proceedDecrypt(string data) 
{

    string decr = key.DecryptString(data);
    decryptedData.Text = decr;
}
```

Hope it helps..!!!

Comment: check the edit, and if error then tell me what error you get....!!! Also how you are calling proceedDecrypt() function ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use encryption and decription with System.Security.Cryptography

```
1) Set encryption decription key
2) Encrypt data with encryption key
3) Decrypt data with same encryption key
```

Please refer below link with Encryption and Decription example. 
[Encryption/Decryption Function in .NET using the TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider Class](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/306620/Encryption-Decryption-Function-in-Net-using-MD-Cry)