# How to encrypt and decrypt connection string

Tags: c#, encryption

I've read several posts but I've yet to find something that helps me.

I've got a simple C# winforms application that connects to a SQL DB. What I want to do is to encrpyt this string and decryt it on the fly. I've found this thread which does what I want - [Encrypting & Decrypting a String in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168240/encrypting-decrypting-a-string-in-c-sharp)

but .... where to I then store the key/saltkey? Any help would be great!

Comment: Ideally, you should put it in your app.config file and either encrypt the config section or the connection string value on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put your connection string in app.config, then you should encrypt your config file, please refer to [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/795135/Encrypt-ConnectionString-in-Web-Config) article to find more details

Comment: Thank you for this, I didn't find that article last night. Looks like it'll do exactly what I want.