# Web API - Token

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-web-api, token

My MVC application makes access to my WEB API.

To access the WEB API is absolutely necessary to inform a "token".

There is a button in the WEB API that generates the token.

**How to make the Web API application only accepts the token generated by MVC application without using database?**

I did the MVC generate the token (a GUID + date) and pass this token to the Web API to validate if the date is within a period of 30s. If within the period I consider that the token is valid.

```
byte [] data = Convert.FromBase64String ( token) ;
When DateTime = DateTime.FromBinary ( BitConverter.ToInt64 (date, 0 ) ) ;

if (when < DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds (-30 ) )
{
    return false;
}
```

This works, however, any GUID that was reported concatenated with a date will be valid. **I need to make my web API knows exactly which token was generated by the MVC application.**

Comment: i would recommend you have look at JWT if not done already https://jwt.io/ and the msdn already has some offering for this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn205065(v=vs.110).aspx. The advantage is it does not persist anything and is secured.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a two-way hash to encrypt the token, then decrypt it server side.  Or to put it another way, manipulate the string in manner that is non-obvious, then perform the opposite operation server side.  This will prevent someone from spoofing your token.  This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168240/encrypting-decrypting-a-string-in-c-sharp) has a lot of details.