# How to Encrypt string with same results in different run times c#

Tags: c#, encryption

I used some apis to Encrypting & Decrypting a String in C# like :
**[Encrypting & Decrypting a String in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168240/encrypting-decrypting-a-string-in-c-sharp)**
 But Encrypting function return different results in different run times.
How can i make it return same results in diffrents run time ?
Thanks !

Comment: If you've done the encryption correctly the run time will have no effect.  Likely you are using a different secret w/ each program your are using for encryption/decryption.  You must share the same secret with all programs that will encrypt/decrypt your data.

Comment: If you refer to the answer with most up votes, then it produces different results each time as it uses random IV and salt each time - and this is not a bad thing ..

Comment: Why do you want same outputs every time? The fact that they are different is [important security feature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_encryption#Leakage) - long story short someone could draw assumptions about your plaintext just by comparing different ciphertexts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i make it return same results in diffrents run time ?

I think you should rather use `Hashing` in such case. Cause hashing when done with the same secret salt key and using the same same hashing mechanism (like `SHA` `HMACSHA`, `MD5`) is guaranteed to generate the same hash key/signature.