# How should I encrypt files that may hold SSNs in C#

Tags: c#, cryptography, system.security

I have some files that users will store on their machines that may have sensitive information such as SSNs. We want to make sure that those files can only be decrypted on the machines they were encrypted on. I was going to use [ProtectedData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata(v=vs.110).aspx) ProtectedData.Protect / ProtectedData.Unprotect ()

to ensure that those files encrypted on one machine can be decrypted on that machine, but do I need to also encrypt the data using something else like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168240/encrypting-decrypting-a-string-in-c-sharp) to encrypt the string in question?

Comment: OpenSSL AES-256 is a great choice that is not too difficult to implement

Comment: ProtectedData seems to do the job you want.

Comment: But if somebody has access to the computer then they could decrypt those files right?

Comment: ProtectedData seems to be able to set the scope to either CurrentUser or LocalMachine

Comment: Secure the machine; don't share username/password