# Converting binary packing c# code to PHP

Tags: c#, php

I am trying to convert the following c# code to PHP but I don't know which pack() arguments to use.

```
var xorkey = BitConverter.ToUInt32(filedata, 0) >> 8;
xorkey *= 0x8083;
for (var i = 8; i < filedata.Length; i += 0x4)
{
    BitConverter.GetBytes(BitConverter.ToUInt32(filedata, i) ^ xorkey).CopyTo(filedata, i);
    xorkey ^= BitConverter.ToUInt32(filedata, i);
}
filedata = filedata.Skip(4).ToArray();
```

Edit - Been working on it, what I have so far appears to work.

```
$xorkey = unpack("L", $filedata)[1] >> 8;
$xorkey *= 32899; // 32899 == 0x8083

for ($i = 8; $i < strlen($filedata); $i += 4) {
    $bytes = unpack("L", substr($filedata, $i))[1] ^ $xorkey;

    // left to do: BitConverter.GetBytes($bytes).CopyTo(filedata, i);

    // this doesn't work: $xorkey ^= unpack("L", substr($filedata, $i))[1];
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do there, but if you are trying to encrypt any data, you should get rid of that (**at least weak**) xor loop and use some strong [cipher encryption algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10177020/1889685). Besides this, the for loop you have, may result in array indexing errors if the data are not of multiply-4 length.

If you still want to convert this piece of code to PHP, then here how you can do it:

**C# code and result**

```
byte[] filedata = new byte[] { 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88 };

var xorkey = BitConverter.ToUInt32(filedata, 0) >> 8;

//xorkey *= 0x8083;
/* It's important to convert the result to UInt32,
 * because the multiplication of a 32bit integer with an other big integer,
 * may result in a 64bit integer
 */
xorkey = Convert.ToUInt32(xorkey * 0x8083);

//Console.WriteLine("xorkey == {0}", xorkey); // xorkey == 4473666

for (var i = 8; i < filedata.Length; i += 0x4)
{
    BitConverter.GetBytes(BitConverter.ToUInt32(filedata, i) ^ xorkey).CopyTo(filedata, i);
    xorkey ^= BitConverter.ToUInt32(filedata, i);
}
filedata = filedata.Skip(4).ToArray();

// Result filedata will contain the following data
// 45 46 47 48 8f 20 c4 8 4 4 4 1c 1c 1c 1c 4 4 4 4 c
```

**PHP code and result**

```
$filedata = pack('C*', 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88);

$xorkey = unpack("L", $filedata)[1] >> 8;
$xorkey = (int)($xorkey * 0x8083);

// echo '$xorkey == '.$xorkey.PHP_EOL; // $xorkey == 4473666

for ($i = 8; $i < strlen($filedata); $i += 4) {
    $n = unpack("L", substr($filedata, $i, 4))[1];
    $filedata = substr_replace($filedata, pack('L', $n ^ $xorkey), $i, 4);
    $xorkey ^= unpack("L", substr($filedata, $i, 4))[1];
}

$filedata = substr($filedata, 4);

// Result $filedata will contain the following data
//45 46 47 48 8f 20 c4 8 4 4 4 1c 1c 1c 1c 4 4 4 4 c
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: $res = unpack("L", $hash,8);

Comment: @user1088259 This code works just fine. Check here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/56c40d2184598cc88358da8b71880d86b7289faf. You're doing something wrong.