# Safe place to keep connection string in wcf library project

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf, connection-string

I have wpf application which is going to use wcf service library. so what is the ideal place to keep connection string( I meant to say wether its wpf project config or wcf project config? and how should i declare it?

Comment: In the App.config file? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: In what sense "safe"? Is it some secret information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hard code sensitive information about service address on your code use some obfuscation tool like [SmartAssembly](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/) and use string encryption feature.
If you want to have this information on app.config file or registry you can use custom encryption\decryption to protect them.

**Update:**

For an example of code refer to:
[Encrypting & Decrypting a String in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168240/encrypting-decrypting-a-string-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I am gone use it in app.config. How to use custom encryption\decryption in app.config file?