# Fix Hardcoded PBE Password

Tags: c#, fortify

We have been using Fortify tool to check for security vulnerabilities, Key Management: Hardcoded PBE Password issue giving hard time to fix.

```
Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 
0x49, 0x76,0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
```

AND

```
using (var password = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(PassPhrase, saltStringBytes, DerivationIterations))
```

I get StringCipher Class from this link [Encrypting & Decrypting a String in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168240/encrypting-decrypting-a-string-in-c-sharp#answer-10177020)

Comment: Did you try converting to string using Encoding? string results = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(login); where login is a byte[].

Comment: @jdweng the issue not in convert but in using Rfc2898DeriveBytes

Comment: See rmalayter answer : https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/47517/is-pbkdf2-rfc-2898-broken-because-sha1-is-broken