# How to manually hash a password using Asp.Net Core 2.2 / IdentityServer4 / SP.NET Core Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

I am migrating tens of thousands of users from an old website that didn't have a password in the database to this new web application, however, when I try to import the users using the async method, it ends up taking several days to the point where I just ended up cancelling it after a few days.

Now I have resorted to just creating new users directly from _context.Users.Add and assigning their roles, which i can do without a problem..  However, I can't seem to figure out how to create a generic password (all the same password) as these users will just be given a password to view a livestream (doesn't need to be super secure), but I still need the security part for the admin accounts that handle other stuff through the client/admin side UI.  If a user signs in, I will have it automatically enter the default password for them.

For some reason though, I cannot get the password hasher to work correctly, as when I sign in, it says that the password is wrong...

This is what I'm using to generate the password and create the users...

```
 var appUser = new ApplicationUser() {
  Id = GenerateId(),
   AccessFailedCount = 0,
   Email = user[1],
   PasswordHash = "",
   FullName = "Standard User",
   UserName = user[1],
   PhoneNumber = user[8],
   FirstName = user[2],
   LastName = user[3],
   JoinMailingList = user[4],
   Country = user[5],
   City = user[6],
   StateRegion = user[7]
 };

 _context.Users.Add(appUser);

 var options = new PasswordHasherOptions();
 options.CompatibilityMode = PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode.IdentityV2;

 var hasher = new PasswordHasher < ApplicationUser > ();
 appUser.PasswordHash = hasher.HashPassword(appUser, "Default8!");

 var role = _context.Roles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name == "user");

 if (role != null) {
  var userRole = new IdentityUserRole < string > ();
  userRole.RoleId = role.Id;
  userRole.UserId = appUser.Id;
  _context.UserRoles.Add(userRole);
 }
}

_context.SaveChanges();
```

Can anyone help me out with how I'm supposed to Hash a password to store into the database?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> If a user signs in, I will have it automatically enter the default password for them.

If you are using .net core Identity, you can use [UserManager.CreateAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.createasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_UserManager_1_CreateAsync__0_System_String_) to create the specified user in the backing store with given password:

```
public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityResult> CreateAsync (TUser user, string password);
```

Code below is for your reference:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "wx2@hotmail.com", Email = "wx2@hotmail.com" };
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "YourPassWord");
if (result.Succeeded)
{

}
```

The Identity system will help create the password hash and store in the database . If you still need to manually hash the password , see [IPasswordHasher interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55124614/asp-net-core-add-secondary-password-to-identityuser/55136202#55136202) .

---

**Edit:**

If you want to directly insert/update via database context, you should set correct `NormalizedUserName` and `SecurityStamp` to make the system work:

```
ApplicationUser applicationUser = new ApplicationUser();
Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
applicationUser.Id = guid.ToString();
applicationUser.UserName = "wx@hotmail.com";
applicationUser.Email = "wx@hotmail.com";
applicationUser.NormalizedUserName = "wx@hotmail.com";

_context.Users.Add(applicationUser);


var hasedPassword = _passwordHasher.HashPassword(applicationUser, "YourPassword");
applicationUser.SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
applicationUser.PasswordHash = hasedPassword;

_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I don't seem to have the ability to enter a password as a parameter for CreateAsync.  It asks for ApplicationUser and CancellationToken.

Comment: I have a CreateUserAsync from the AccountManager.  The problem is that this method takes an extremely long time to complete.  Especially for over 100k accounts.  It seemingly creating one account half a second or second.

Comment: @AlexLiosatos , see update reply and check whether it helps .

Comment: @AlexLiosatos it took me between 3,5 and 4 minutes to create 1000 Application Users with "await userManager.CreateAsync(applicationUser, "Test123!");" (and "userManager.AddClaimsAsync"). I generated applicationUser in a for loop with SubjectId "TestSubjectId" + the index, Name "TestName" + the index and some Claimes.

Comment: Using the DbContext it took ~26s for 1000 Users and finally using DbContext and addRange it took me around 12s but without Adding Claims. Use the DbContext as NanYu said, it helps alot!

Comment: Marked this as the correct answer.. In all reality, it was the security stamp that was holding me back.. Once I added that in, it worked out and all 100k were created in just a couple minutes using _context.  The issue I had is that logins still wouldn't work without a proper security stamp.

Comment: Thousands of users could be created within a minutes if you will just create a Console App and add users directly in database (of course you will have to add proper Nuget packages in your App, such as Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity etc.)

Answer (score 2):

As an addition, if you just want to Update the Password field of an given User:

```
var oldUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

var result = await _userManager.ChangePasswordAsync(oldUser,
                    updateUserVm.CurrentPassword,
                    updateUserVm.NewPassword);
```

And an example to the Question "How I'm supposed to Hash a password?". You could Hash a registered Users Password with the UserManager-Referenced PasswordHasher like this:

```
ApplicationUser user = _userManager.Users...;
user.PasswordHash = _userManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(user, newPassword);
```

Answer (score 0):

I write my class PasswordHasher based on **.net6** PasswordHasher docs latest version (V3) in this stackoverflow answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72429730/9875486