# How do I add authentication to an ASP.NET Core minimal API using Identity, but without using Azure?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-identity, minimal-apis

I'm sure the answer to this must be obvious, as it's an obvious thing want to do, but I can't seem to find any guidance.

I have an ASP.NET Core minimal API, and want to add authentication. I already have Identity set up in a different project, and want to use the same database (ie the same users) for the API.

I saw [this blog post](https://dotnetthoughts.net/implementing-basic-authentication-in-minimal-webapi/), which looked promising until I realised that the code there checks the user name and password as plain text (using `admin` as both in the sample)...

```cs
if (credentials[0] == "admin" && credentials[1] == "admin")
```

The problem with this is that (thankfully), Identity does not store the passwords in plain text, they are hashed, so I can't do a simple comparison.

I tried hashing the incoming password, as [shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55825865/706346), but that didn't work as the hash came out different every time I called `_userManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword`.

I tried using the ASP.NET Core's `SignInManager.CanSignInAsync` method to check if I could sign in with the credentials, but that required me to add the following to `Program`...

```cs
builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(options => {
    // options removed for clarity
  })
  .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
```

However, as soon as I did this, any request to the API attempted to redirect to a log-in page, which is obviously not going to work when the API is being called from code.

All I could find on Microsoft's site was [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-configuration), but that assumes you are using Azure. At the moment, I'm still developing this on my local machine, and I don't know yet whether the project owners want to deploy to Azure or their own hosted server, so the code there doesn't help me.

Anyone able to explain to me how I do what seems like such an obvious and simple task? Please let me know if there is any more info I need to provide. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you seen Bipin Joshi's series of articles on this subject? My guess is that you are past the first few, but you might find these useful...

[Implement JWT Authentication In ASP.NET Core Minimal APIs](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/082e1b54-86ec-495a-86fb-be260830947c.aspx)

[Integrate ASP.NET Core Identity With JWT And Minimal APIs](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/2a3e0320-3f91-4237-a1f8-4c2932a3fd00.aspx)

The one change I made when using that approach was that the `getToken` API call just takes two `string` parameters for the user name and password, instead of a `User` object. Given that it's only two parameters, I find this makes life easier when working with disparate projects, as you don't need the class definition. Up to you though.

In order to call the API, you'll need to call `getToken` first, passing in the user name and password. Once you have your token, you can then set the authentication on your `HtpClient` as follows...

```cs
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
```

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I needed, thanks. Only had a brief read, but one thing that seems missing is that it only tells you how to call the API from Swagger. Obviously I want to call it from my code. I guess I have to call `getToken` first, but then how do I pass the token to the API? Thanks again.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel Updated my answer. Does that help?