# Encrypting file conent and decrypt it while reading C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am using entity framework(WebAPI/C#/VS2019) and using below code to save file and display file.

**Save Code**

```
 Document document = new Document();
 var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(attachment_data);  //attachment_data is string
                    document.document_content=plainTextBytes;//document_content is  byte[]

                    db.Documents.Add(document);
                    db.SaveChanges();
```

**Below code is used to show saved file**

```
 [Route("api/documents/download")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Download(int documentid)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var document = db.Documents.Where(e => e.id.Equals(documentid)).FirstOrDefault();

        if (document != null)
        {
            var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(document.document_content);
            result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = document.name

            };
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Both Save file and downloading file is working fine.
The issue is how to encrypt the file content before Saving to Database?I saw [few SO links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168240/encrypting-decrypting-a-string-in-c-sharp) but most of the methods are taking string as input and string as output.Not sure which one will fit in this scenario.

Comment: The top answer you've linked to turns the string into bytes for processing: `var plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);` So just use your document bytes as plainTextBytes instead.

Comment: `Convert.FromBase64String(System.Convert.ToBase64String` seems like a good way of burning up cycles for no particular benefit. Why not just `document.document_content = plainTextBytes`?

Comment: Most of encryption method work with a byte array and not a string to encrypt/decrypt. As far as I could see, your document is a byte array.

Comment: You can use AES encryption to encrypt the file before saving into the database, and use it to decrypt the file after retrieve from the database.