# Does the AES c# code for encrypting and decrypting a string work in Android 4.1 or 5

Tags: android, xamarin, encryption, cryptography, aes

I want to use the AES C# code given in the following website

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=netcore-3.1

for encrypting and decrypting a string using AES .

I want to use encrypting and decrypting C# code in Xamarin for Android 4.1 and 5.

I am having this doubt, because if we move to the end of the above mentioned webpage it says

Applies to

Xamarin.Android

7.1

Does that mean it is absolutely impossible to use the above code.
If that is the case what is the AES C# code for encrypting and decrypting a string that can be applied in Xamarin for Android 4.1 and 5

Answer (score 0):

It's not that AES encryption and decryption isn't possible to express in Xamarin for Android 4+, it's just simply that this library (or class) isn't present in that version of the SDK.

If this class isn't exposed as part of the 4.0+ SDK, you could simply use another lib.

Comment: Which is that lib ? Where does this exist ?

Comment: If you want to  encrypting and decrypting a string with C#, this url may be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168240/encrypting-decrypting-a-string-in-c-sharp