# Class with broken AES encryption service after upgrading from .Net 5 to .Net 6

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography, aes

I have the following class with service for AES encryption and decryption. Everything works fine until .Net 5. After migrating to .Net 6, the decryption method returns incomplete text.

Cryptography class:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace framework.mstiCSharp.Services
{
    public class CriptografiaService
    {
        #region Settings

        private static int _iterations = 2;
        private static int _keySize = 256;

        private static string _hash = "SHA1";
        private static string _salt = "aselrias38490a32"; // Random
        private static string _vector = "8947az34awl34kjq"; // Random

        #endregion 

        public static string Encrypt(string value, string AesKey)
        {
            return Encrypt<AesManaged>(value, AesKey);
        }

        private static string Encrypt<RijndaelManaged>(string value, string password)
                where RijndaelManaged : SymmetricAlgorithm, new()
        {
            byte[] vectorBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_vector);
            byte[] saltBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_salt);
            byte[] valueBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);

            byte[] encrypted;
            using (RijndaelManaged cipher = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                PasswordDeriveBytes _passwordBytes =
                    new PasswordDeriveBytes(password, saltBytes, _hash, _iterations);
                byte[] keyBytes = _passwordBytes.GetBytes(_keySize / 8);

                cipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = cipher.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, vectorBytes))
                {
                    using (MemoryStream to = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (CryptoStream writer = new CryptoStream(to, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            writer.Write(valueBytes, 0, valueBytes.Length);
                            writer.FlushFinalBlock();
                            encrypted = to.ToArray();
                        }
                    }
                }
                cipher.Clear();
            }
            return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
        }

        public static string Decrypt(string value, string AesKey)
        {
            return Decrypt<AesManaged>(value, AesKey);
        }

        private static string Decrypt<T>(string value, string password) where T : SymmetricAlgorithm, new()
        {
            byte[] vectorBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_vector);
            byte[] saltBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_salt);
            byte[] valueBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(value);

            byte[] decrypted;
            int decryptedByteCount = 0;

            using (T cipher = new T())
            {
                PasswordDeriveBytes _passwordBytes = new PasswordDeriveBytes(password, saltBytes, _hash, _iterations);
                byte[] keyBytes = _passwordBytes.GetBytes(_keySize / 8);

                cipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                try
                {
                    using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = cipher.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, vectorBytes))
                    {
                        using (MemoryStream from = new MemoryStream(valueBytes))
                        {
                            using (CryptoStream reader = new CryptoStream(from, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                            {
                                decrypted = new byte[valueBytes.Length];
                                decryptedByteCount = reader.Read(decrypted, 0, decrypted.Length);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return String.Empty;
                }

                cipher.Clear();
            }
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted, 0, decryptedByteCount);
        }
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
using framework.mstiCSharp.Services;
using Xunit;

namespace framework.mstiCSharpTest
{
    public class CriptografiaServiceTest
    {
        [Theory]
        [InlineData("abc123")]
        [InlineData("Silvair Leite Soares")]
        [InlineData("abcdefghij 1234567890")]
        public void encriptTest(string originalText)        
        {
            string key = "1sFnWG4HnV8TZY30iTOdtVWJG8abWvB1GlOgJuQZdcF2Luqm";

            string encriptText = CriptografiaService.Encrypt(originalText, key); 
            string decriptText = CriptografiaService.Decrypt(encriptText, key);

            Assert.Equal(originalText, decriptText);
        }
    }
}
```

I found this other question [Problem Updating to .Net 6 - Encrypting String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69911084/problem-updating-to-net-6-encrypting-string), and this issue [AES Encryption broken on Dot Net 6](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/61918), on this same subject. But I couldn't adapt the answers and suggestions to my situation.

**Test cases:**

| Test | 1 |
| --- | --- |
| Original text | Silvair Leite Soares |
| After encryption | u2LcEdwpyTT4j+YJSYenJzFz0o+t0027DbvOn/i8bjU= |
| After decrypting | Silvair Leite So |

| Test | 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Original text | abc123 |
| After encryption | k3tyVen0ulvrsLJ/MuVevA== |
| After decrypting | abc123 |

| Test | 3 |
| --- | --- |
| Original text | abcdefghij 1234567890 |
| After encryption | BUCUPbc1PhLOBvV9R2XP2NE7bWYQi5O4BjciiZd70pI= |
| After decrypting | abcdefghij 12345 |

As can be seen, in some situations, with smaller text, it still works. But in larger texts, it fails every time.

Any help will be most welcome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem Updating to .Net 6 - Encrypting String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69911084/problem-updating-to-net-6-encrypting-string). With regard to the UTF-8 decoding you performed at the end of your decryption, probably the last option in the accepted answer is the easiest (applying `StreamReader#ReadToEnd()`).

Comment: Topaco, thanks for the suggestion. I even mentioned this other question in my question.
But I couldn't adapt the suggestions of the answers of this other question to my case. Would you help me?

Comment: See here for a possible fix: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qoz0gE.

Comment: I managed to solve. I will write an answer to my own question.
Thank you Topaco.

Comment: Your suggestion solves my case. If you want to write an answer, I'll be happy to mark it as the solution.
Thank you very much Topaco.