# AES Decryption From Hex to Plain Text using key in C#

Tags: c#, encryption, hex, aes

//Encryption is working fine, but decryption is not working properly - In Decryption (I'll pass **Encrypted Hex data** in content and key as Password and expect **Plain Text**).

// Encryption working perfectly
public string Encrypt(string content, string password)
{
string content = "  OTME00005XXZ43 ";
string password = "2E77A838E00A4A29D6F7CF418D55AC32";

```
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);

    using (SymmetricAlgorithm crypt = Aes.Create())
    using (HashAlgorithm hash = MD5.Create())
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        crypt.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        crypt.Key = hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
        // This is really only needed before you call CreateEncryptor the second time,
        // since it starts out random.  But it's here just to show it exists.
        crypt.IV = new byte[16] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f };

        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(
            memoryStream, crypt.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cryptoStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }

        string base64IV = Convert.ToBase64String(crypt.IV);
        string base64Ciphertext = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
        byte[] decoded = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Ciphertext);
        string resultAsHex = (BitConverter.ToString(decoded).Replace("-", string.Empty));
        return resultAsHex;
    }
}
// Output is - 53F66CD9910F0934CA97197C914849B645D8F589F73148217EB92A850E317C3E446814780A66A7F246DEA99E2E8DF56FF1217A8714D959D4BFA35833386CBDD8362ED399CA4A0A68BC10D347B15780910ECB2B7FB1B266C933A576648C6F9C8EB808894D91D4567F738F7BFAE1117E9B1751CBE9F9011EE930811622436DEA3F


private void Decrypt()
{
    //length of 608 char string, so content can needed for padding.
    string content = "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";
    string password = "2E77A838E00A4A29D6F7CF418D55AC32";

    //Decrypt
    //byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(content);
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
    SymmetricAlgorithm crypt = Aes.Create();
    HashAlgorithm hash = MD5.Create();
    crypt.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
    crypt.Key = hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
    // This is really only needed before you call CreateEncryptor the second time,
    // since it starts out random.  But it's here just to show it exists.
    crypt.IV = new byte[16] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f };

    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream =
           new CryptoStream(memoryStream, crypt.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        {
            byte[] decryptedBytes = new byte[bytes.Length];
            cryptoStream.Read(decryptedBytes, 0, decryptedBytes.Length);
            string result = Convert.ToBase64String(decryptedBytes);
            Response.Write(result);
        }
    }



}
```

Above encryption working perfectly but decryption is not working perfectly, because if same encrypted Hex data passed to decryption then not getting plain text. Previously I made some changes to decryption but then getting error (padding is invalid and cannot be removed.)

Comment: In the `Decrypt()` method `content` is not to be UTF-8 encoded but hex decoded. As padding PKCS#7 must be applied. Furthermore `decryptedBytes` must not be Base64 encoded but UTF-8 decoded.

Comment: Note that your code will probably not run with .NET 6, see this [breaking change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69911546) regarding `Read()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solve issue, thanks buddy @Topaco, Sorry for duplicate question.

```
 public static string DecryptAES(string cipherText)
    {
        string plaintext = null;

        //for add Hex string to char '-' to 2, 4, 6 and so on
        cipherText = Regex.Replace(cipherText, ".{2}", "$0-");
        cipherText = cipherText.Remove(cipherText.Length - 1);
        int length = (cipherText.Length + 1) / 3;

        //for string to byte array
        byte[] encrypted = new byte[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            encrypted[i] = Convert.ToByte(cipherText.Substring(3 * i, 2), 16);
        // Create AesManaged    
        using (AesManaged aes = new AesManaged())
        {
            HashAlgorithm hash = MD5.Create();
            aes.Key = hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("2E77A838E00A4A29D6F7CF418D55AC32"));
            aes.IV = new byte[16] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f };
            // Create a decryptor    
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
            // Create the streams used for decryption.    
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(encrypted))
            {
                // Create crypto stream    
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    // Read crypto stream    
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(cs))
                        plaintext = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        return plaintext;
    }
```