# Create decryptable encrypted string

Tags: c#, encryption, .net-8.0

I need to store some encrypted data and then (in second time) read the original value, I don't need very strong encryption, just much as the user can't be able to manipulate those string(s).

I'm trying this code:

```
 public static string Encrypt(string plainText)
 {
     if (Settings.LicenseOK())
     {

         byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);

         var symmetricKey = Aes.Create();
         //symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
         symmetricKey.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
         ICryptoTransform encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor();
         using MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
         using CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

         cs.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
         cs.FlushFinalBlock();
         ms.Flush();
         return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray(), Base64FormattingOptions.None);

     }
     else
         throw (new Exception("Errore nella DLL GDWS"));
  }

  public static string Decrypt(string cipherText)
  {
     if (Settings.LicenseOK())
     {
         byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

         var symmetricKey = Aes.Create();
         //symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
         symmetricKey.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

         byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];

         ICryptoTransform decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor();
         using MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes);
         using CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);

         cs.Read(plainTextBytes);
         return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes);
     }
     else
         throw (new Exception("Errore nella DLL GDWS"));
 }
}
```

But every time I encrypt a string, the encrypted one changes (I think it has to remain the same or it can't be decrypted), and I cannot revert the process (decryption) (the decryption process takes to an incomprehensible yet always different string).

Please help me.

Comment: [This is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69911546/107625) (together with the initial question) that helped me to develop string encrypt and decrypt methods.

Comment: You are ASSUMING in two places that the encrypted string is the same length as the plaintext.  Do you have any evidence that this is actually the case?

Comment: You're not setting the Key and IV of your AES instance, so those will be different each time. You want to generate those Key and IV once, store safely and then set those properties when you need to encrypt/decrypt.  https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUKgBgAJVMA6AZQFMBjCMAS2AE8yBhMZgB2AHsBzMAEMuAC2YBuAJAyZeVAGYS6EpgDseAN54pGdDu24ZANyFgiQqgGciAXiIBBa+zBUhwKgAoAlBJ27MAE5PACIAaypmEE0CAF8YIgZjaMxYkIS2XihjKjBgMgAVXgAhISsqADYAFgpgRih+T0srMgBpSO8MrJy8wpKyypq6hgam5wBJADVvXx1YvFigA===

Comment: The random key and IV generated for each encryption are the reason for the ciphertext changing each time. While, as mentioned in the last comment, the key is (usually) generated once (and then reused), this should not be done for the IV for security reasons. Instead, a random IV should be generated for each encryption and sent to the decrypting side together with the ciphertext. Also, the more reliable PKCS#7 padding should be preferred to the unreliable Zero padding. Note that both issues (among others) are covered by the post linked in the first comment.

Comment: "I don't need strong encryption." Once more for those in back: there is no such thing as weak encryption. It's either military grade strong, or completely worthless, and there is no effective middle ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to preserve the **same key** between encryption and decryption.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to store some encrypted data and then (in second time) read the original value, I don't need very strong encryption, just much as the user can't be able to manipulate those string(s).

An authenticated cipher mode such as GCM mode is required for that. CBC only offers confidentiality, and then only when applied correctly; it doesn't offer message integrity or authentication. According to the statement above integrity would be required. Actually, confidentiality is not even stated as a requirement, so you may be fine by just protecting the integrity & authenticity by using a MAC such as HMAC or a signature.

> But every time I encrypt a string, the encrypted one changes (I think it has to remain the same or it can't be decrypted).

No that's the wrong idea; fully secure ciphers need to create indistinguishable (i.e. random looking) output even if the adversary chooses the message to be encrypted. This falls under IND-CPA i.e. indistinguishability under chosen plaintext attack. This is why each message should be encrypted with a different IV / key combination. For CBC the IV needs to be fully unpredictable, which usually means that the IV is chosen using a secure random number generator.'

To decrypt both the key and the IV needs to be identical. The key is often established beforehand and may be identical for multiple messages. The IV needs to be established between the encryption agent and the decryption agent for each message, e.g. by prefixing it to the ciphertext. In the end the way that the key and IV are established depends on the protocol used (derived from a password, RSA/hybrid encryption, DH-key agreement etc. etc. etc.).