# AES encryption working but returning too short text (only working on short plain texts)

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I've been using the following code to encrypt some password in my application. The original code was listed here [Encrypting & Decrypting a String in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168240/encrypting-decrypting-a-string-in-c-sharp). And I've updated it to fit the requirements of .NET6.

It was working as expected with Hashing Algorithm SHA1, but the update to .NET 8 required a change to another algorithm e.g. SHA512.

It's still decrypting correctly but only returns the first few characters. Any Hint why this is happening?

The original question is closed, so this is a new one.

```cs
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Text;

namespace AesEncryption
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Extension class for encryption based on an algorithm described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168240/encrypting-decrypting-a-string-in-c-sharp
    /// Changed the fixed derivationIterations to a random short-number and algorithm to AesCng.
    /// Changed HashAlgorithm to SHA512, as SHA1 became deprecated
    /// </summary>
    public static class GlobalEncryptionAes
    {
        public static string Encrypt(this string plainText)
        {
            return Encrypt(plainText, GeneratePassPhrase());
        }

        public static string Encrypt(this string plainText, string passPhrase)
        {
            // DerivationIterations, Salt and IV are randomly generated each time, but is prepended to encrypted cipher text, so they can be used for decryption
            byte[] derivationIterationsBytes = GenerateBitsOfRandomEntropy(2);
            int derivationIterations = (int)BitConverter.ToUInt16(derivationIterationsBytes);
            if (derivationIterations == 0) derivationIterations++;

            byte[] saltStringBytes = GenerateBitsOfRandomEntropy(32);
            byte[] ivStringBytes = GenerateBitsOfRandomEntropy(16);
            byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
            using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes password = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passPhrase, saltStringBytes, derivationIterations, HashAlgorithmName.SHA512))
            {
                var keyBytes = password.GetBytes(32);
                using (AesCng symmetricKey = new AesCng())
                {
                    symmetricKey.KeySize = 256;
                    symmetricKey.BlockSize = 128;
                    symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                    symmetricKey.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                    using (var encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, ivStringBytes))
                    {
                        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                            {
                                cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

                                // Create the final bytes as a concatenation of the random derivation iteration bytes, the random salt bytes, the random iv bytes and the cipher bytes.
                                byte[] cipherTextBytes;
                                cipherTextBytes = derivationIterationsBytes;
                                cipherTextBytes = cipherTextBytes.Concat(saltStringBytes).ToArray();
                                cipherTextBytes = cipherTextBytes.Concat(ivStringBytes).ToArray();
                                cipherTextBytes = cipherTextBytes.Concat(memoryStream.ToArray()).ToArray();
                                memoryStream.Close();
                                cryptoStream.Close();

                                return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// decrypts a string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cipherText">encrypted string</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string Decrypt(this string cipherText)
        {
            return Decrypt(cipherText, GeneratePassPhrase());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// decrypts a string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cipherText">encrypted string</param>
        /// <param name="passPhrase">encryption key</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string Decrypt(this string cipherText, string passPhrase)
        {
            // Get the complete stream of bytes that represent:
            // [2 byte of Derivation Iteration], [32 bytes of Salt] + [16 bytes of IV] + [n bytes of CipherText]
            byte[] cipherTextBytesWithDerivationIterationSaltIv = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

            if (cipherTextBytesWithDerivationIterationSaltIv.Length <= 50)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("cipherText is not valid");
            }

            // Get the DerivationIterationBytes by extracting the first 2 bytes from the supplied cipherText bytes.
            byte[] derivationIterationsBytes = cipherTextBytesWithDerivationIterationSaltIv.Take(2).ToArray();
            int derivationIterations = (int)BitConverter.ToUInt16(derivationIterationsBytes);

            // Get the saltStringBytes by extracting the next 32 bytes from the supplied cipherText bytes.
            byte[] saltStringBytes = cipherTextBytesWithDerivationIterationSaltIv.Skip(2).Take(32).ToArray();

            // Get the ivStringBytes by extracting the next 24 bytes from the supplied cipherText bytes.
            byte[] ivStringBytes = cipherTextBytesWithDerivationIterationSaltIv.Skip(34).Take(16).ToArray();

            // Get the actual cipher text bytes by removing the first 58 bytes (2 + 32 + 16) from the cipherText string.
            byte[] cipherTextBytes = cipherTextBytesWithDerivationIterationSaltIv.Skip(50).Take(cipherTextBytesWithDerivationIterationSaltIv.Length - 50).ToArray();

            using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes password = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passPhrase, saltStringBytes, derivationIterations, HashAlgorithmName.SHA512))
            {
                var keyBytes = password.GetBytes(32);
                using (AesCng symmetricKey = new AesCng())
                {
                    symmetricKey.KeySize = 256;
                    symmetricKey.BlockSize = 128;
                    symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                    symmetricKey.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                    using (var decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, ivStringBytes))
                    {
                        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes))
                        {
                            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                            {
                                byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];
                                var decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                                memoryStream.Close();
                                cryptoStream.Close();

                                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// generates string dependent on machine name and user name and SID of user
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>passphrase</returns>
        private static string GeneratePassPhrase()
        {
            string machineName;
            string currentUserName;
            SecurityIdentifier? currentUserSecurityIdentifier;
            string currentUserSecurityIdentifierString;
            string passPhrasString;
            byte[] passPhraseBytes;

            machineName = Environment.MachineName;
            currentUserName = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
            currentUserSecurityIdentifier = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User;
            if (currentUserSecurityIdentifier is not null)
            {
                currentUserSecurityIdentifierString = currentUserSecurityIdentifier.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                currentUserSecurityIdentifierString = "";
            }

            passPhrasString = machineName + currentUserName + currentUserSecurityIdentifierString;
            passPhraseBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passPhrasString);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(passPhraseBytes);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// generates entropy
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>random entropy of length</returns>
        public static byte[] GenerateBitsOfRandomEntropy(byte numberOfBytes)
        {
            byte[] randomBytes = new byte[numberOfBytes];

            RandomNumberGenerator.Fill(randomBytes);

            return randomBytes;
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string plainText = "abc";
            Console.WriteLine(plainText);

            string cypherText = plainText.Encrypt();
            Console.WriteLine(cypherText);

            plainText = cypherText.Decrypt();
            Console.WriteLine(plainText);




            plainText = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            Console.WriteLine(plainText);

            cypherText = plainText.Encrypt();
            Console.WriteLine(cypherText);

            plainText = cypherText.Decrypt();
            Console.WriteLine(plainText);
        }
    }
}
```

The above code results in following output:

Short text works as expected

```
        string plainText = "abc";
        Console.WriteLine(plainText);

        string cypherText = plainText.Encrypt();
        Console.WriteLine(cypherText);

        plainText = cypherText.Decrypt();
        Console.WriteLine(plainText);
```

**Output**

```
abc
rsWFdjY34byN8xxMt/pJxXc4s0Nvi/HwZEW9g0KFhAS+qqi+qlTlbHg73WN49HNOxSB4jXPqqev7MucKwyLvUepR
abc
```

Longer text is decrypted correctly BUT truncated

```
        plainText = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        Console.WriteLine(plainText);

        cypherText = plainText.Encrypt();
        Console.WriteLine(cypherText);

        plainText = cypherText.Decrypt();
        Console.WriteLine(plainText);
```

**Output**

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
xoTpfRH4GIMrB4KrrjWxAy872n3dCAvGZteJCb1W+xfX3jIa9ZFFn94lUhhxwQWaJzh1lAi/B44ZXrYCQK67u3z4BZIelPxEBHfuFeEXKsIJiA==
abcdefghijklmnop
```

My expectation would be the same plain text without truncation.
When using the deprecated SHA1 the above code works as expected with the full text, as far as I am aware of.

Comment: So for me the code already does not work on .NET 6 (not even with SHA-1). The reason is that your updates for .NET 6 are not sufficient because [this breaking change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/partial-byte-reads-in-streams) was not taken into account during decryption. In [this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69911546/9014097) you will find suggested solutions (via `CopyTo()`, `ReadToEnd()`,...).

Comment: thanks for the link, will test this tomorrow and update accordingly

Comment: Do not include the answer in your question. Instead add your own answer and accept it. That’s how it’s supposed to be done on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Topaco in the comments:

> So for me the code already does not work on .NET 6 (not even with
> SHA-1). The reason is that your updates for .NET 6 are not sufficient
> because this breaking change was not taken into account during
> decryption. In this SO Post you will find suggested solutions (via
> CopyTo(), ReadToEnd(),...).
>
> -- Topaco

the `CryptoStream` stops early when reading from it.

Changing the last part of the decryption to use a `StreamReader` and `ReadToEnd()` gets the complete text.

```cs
using (var decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, ivStringBytes))
{
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes))
    {
        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        {
            using (StreamReader plainTextReader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream))
            {
                plainText = plainTextReader.ReadToEnd();

                memoryStream.Close();
                cryptoStream.Close();
            }

            return plainText;
        }
    }
}
```

Using this the decryption is working as expected.